# No puedo cambiar de color el fill SVG

Tags: css, svg, color, hover

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#FFF;" d="M479.882,137.272l0.001-0.007l-0.004,0.003c-27.907-35.488-77.51-86.066-133.571-86.066l0,0....
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento con

```
svg path:hover {
fill: red; 
}
```

pero me cambia la línea negra del borde.

¿Cómo puedo **acceder al style fill dentro de path en CSS**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vale resuelto, he borrado la propiedad style inline y ya funciona!

Comment: Te invito a leer [answer]. Tu respuesta, aunque acertada podría estar mejor explicada. Saludos